# Data Driven Pages Navigation in a Script

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, data-driven-pages

Is there a method to simply progress from one data driven page to the next in a script?  Essentially, like pressing the "Next Page" button on the toolbar.  I have started with:

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy,mapping.mapdocument ("Current") # or should I reference the mxd directly?
ddp = mxd.datadrivenpages
cp  = ddp.currentPageID
np  = cp + 1              #Advance to next PageID?
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
```

But cannot seem to find a way to advance to the next page, most searches yield methods to only export the pages.

The end goal is to build a tool that advances to the next data driven page and selects all features in a layer that has a page definition set to match the index.  This will facilitate attribute editing for the selected features.

The image below shows the selection model which works just fine, I just need to be able to script something to move forward a page and then run the Model (or script it all) to simplify the process.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're assigning an integer value to a variable, not to your data driven pages.  You are setting `np = cp + 1`, so, for example, if your current page is `2` then:

```
np = cp + 1
```

will return

```
np = 3
```

but `np` doesn't actually mean or do anything.

Instead you need to set `mxd.dataDrivenPages.currentPageID = mxd.dataDrivenPages.currentPageID + 1` (or `mxd.dataDrivenPages.currentPageID = cp + 1`)

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument ("Current") 
ddp = mxd.dataDrivenPages
ddp.currentPageID += 1
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
```

---

As an aside, double-check all your code for correct syntax/caps/formatting.  There are a lot of typos in your code snippet above that I had to fix to test.  A comma `,` instead of a period `.` and several lowercase letters `mxd.datadrivenpages` instead of `mxd.dataDrivenPages` etc.  Python is VERY picky on these points!

Comment: Corrections per your comments do indeed make the script work.  Your are correct that Python is very picky, I usually make those simple mistakes and scratch my head until I notice them.  Thank you.